# How can I delete characters from a given string? (String manipulation in python)

Tags: python, string, counter

I have a string="aabbcdb", I want to delete the characters which have occurred twice.
It would be better if you answer me using Counter module.
PS: I want the answer to be 'cdb'. Coz that's what remains when we delete the twice occurring characters.

Comment: a very easy way is, split that string into a array (`split("aabbcdb", "") -> ["a","a","b",...]`), then create a set of that array (`set(splitedArray) -> ["a", "b", "c", "d"] `) at last join them! (`join(setArr, "") -> "abcd"`), Now, It's your tasks to create those functions, Although those basic functions is included in many programing language...

Comment: Do you care about whether the pairs of letters you're deleting are adjacent? E.g. would `"aba"` turn into `"b"`? Do you care about multiples of 2, or only the first pair of a given letter?

Comment: Oh Yes! They should be adjacent.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to delete character in specific position,you can do like this.

```py
def f(string,pos):
    return string[:pos]+string[pos+1:]
>>> s='abcd'
>>> f(s,1)
'acd'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a list as a stack to keep track of the previous character and pop off the stack if the current character is the same as the previous

```
new_string = [string[0]]
i = 0

for char in string[1:]:
    if new_string != [] and new_string[len(new_string)-1] == char:
        new_string.pop(len(new_string)-1)
    else:
        new_string.append(char)
        i += 1

print("".join(new_string))
```

Comment: I also tried this way.